# How would a new puppy affect a 3.5 year old male Black Lab?

Tags: dogs, multi-pet-families

I currenly own a 3.5 year old male Black Lab. He is well trained, well exercised and a great family dog. I've always wanted a German Shepherd and am considering purchasing a GSD puppy (not sure if it would be a male or female yet). I'm curious what I might expect from our Black Lab as far as behaviour changes, if any. I'm pretty sure if I were to bring in an adult GSD, I could expect problems. But, bringing in a puppy, I'm not so sure.